# every time i code at least one line of code xcode takes around 3 minutes to build or run

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Every time I code at least one line of code `Xcode` takes around 3 minutes to build or run, want to know is this a `Xcode8` bug with `Swift3` or not? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the line of code that takes 3 minutes to build? Can you provide some examples? Generally, this is not an issue with Xcode 8 since I compile a fair number of projects which are all Swift 3 and they compile fine.

Comment: Does it take 3 minutes if your code is in Objective-C? You may wanna try that to see if it's the problem of the programming language.

Comment: Try to clean and build the project. (shift + cmd + k)

Comment: It takes around 1  to 2 second to compile every .swift file. I tried with Objective-C this issue doesn't apppear.